# Standard deviation mismatch when computing from scratch

Tags: pine-script

What is wrong with the code below to calculate standard deviation using the mathematical functions provided by Pine Script (I don't get the same result as when using `stdev`):

```
mid = sma(close, period)
sigma = sqrt(sum(pow(close - mid, 2), period)/period)
```

---

Here is what I don't understand. The equations below show that both `sigma1` and `sigma2` should produce the same plot, but it does not. What is the explanation for this:

```
sigma1 = sqrt(sum(pow(close - mid, 2), period)/period)
sigma2 = sqrt(sma(close*close, period) - pow(sma(close, period), 2))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Methods 2 and 3 yield same results as the naive algo used in Pine.

With method 3 using alexgrover's functions [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/), you can use a series length:

```
//@version=4
study("StDev")
period = input(20)

// ————— 1
mid = sma(close, period)
sigma = sqrt(sum(pow(close - mid, 2), period)/period)
// ————— 2
f_stdev(src,p) => p == 1 ? 0 : sqrt(sma(src*src,p) - pow(sma(src,p),2))
// ————— 3
Sma(src,p) => a = cum(src), (a - a[max(p,0)])/max(p,0)
Stdev(src,p) => p == 1 ? 0 : sqrt(Sma(src*src,p) - pow(Sma(src,p),2))

plot(sigma, "1", color.fuchsia)
plot(f_stdev(close, period), "2", color.blue, 16, transp = 80)
plot(Stdev(close, period), "3", color.blue, 8, transp = 60)
plot(stdev(close, period), "4", color.gray, 2, transp = 0)
```

Yours is in fuchsia here:

[image]

---

#### [EDIT: 2020.02.22 21:29 — LucF]

Doing it your way would require a `for` loop:

```
mean = sma(close, period)
sum = 0.0
for i=0 to period-1
    sum := sum + pow(nz(close[i]) - mean, 2)
sigma = sqrt(sum / period)
```

Comment: Thanks @PineCoders-LucF - I have added more information to my question. Please see the equations; it shows that both `sigma1` (in blue) and `sigma2` (in red) should be the same. What is going on?

Comment: Interesting. Why doesn't the `sum` function work in this case, and the for loop is needed instead? I want to better understand Pine Script.